# highest scores- Sort numbers from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am very beginner in php so I am sorry for such a simple question. I need to make High score list- sorted from highest score to the lowest. The scores are in databse altogether wih nickname.

i know i should use asort, but i tried many different ways but i doesnt work.I dont know how to formulate it.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

html table

<?php
}
asort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);
$result = array_reverse($result, true);
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY score DESC`?

Comment: You could also make use of [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and other similar SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort in PHP. Use an `order by` clause in your SQL query.

`"SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY SCORE"`

You can, of course, add `desc` to sort descending.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Add Order By clause to the select and remove sorting from PHP like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY score DESC;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

html table

<?php
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>
```